# Pouchdb wait for promise inside promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, pouchdb

The following code does not give the expected output:

```
function downloadData() {
    var timeStamp = new Date();

    db.upsert("timeData", function(doc) {
        if (!doc.nextRun) {
            doc.nextRun = timeStamp.getTime();
        }

        if (doc.nextRun < timeStamp.getTime()) {
            console.log("yes")

            timeStamp.setSeconds(timeStamp.getSeconds() + 10);
            doc.nextRun = timeStamp.getTime();

            api.commerce().prices().all().then(function(items) {
                return Promise.all(items.map(function(item) {
                    // do something with item
                    return;
                }));
            }).then(function(){
                console.log("data processed")
                return doc;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("no")
            return doc;
        }
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Done")
    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
}
```

The output is

```
yes
Done
data processed
```

But I am expecting

```
yes
data processed
Done
```

I understand this is a promise issue but I am not very experienced with this and could use some advice. Now the `return doc` also seems to trigger too late and thus the data is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the inner promise:

```
return api.commerce().prices().all().then(function(items) { 
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I also tried that, but I still get the same output.